# Automating iOS browser of a connected device on Linux

Tags: python, ios, testing, mobile, selenium

Is there a way to automate iPod touch browser with Selenium (or something other similar) under Linux? There is an iOS driver for Selenium but it seems to be OSX only.

I would want to do some basic browser based tests or going through pages and making screenshots of them for layout testing (with Python).